# How do I Use Dock to Bottom without affecting the curent page's viewport height in Chrome developer tools? I don't want to undock separate window

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

How do I Use Dock to Bottom without affecting the Viewport height in Chrome developer tools?
I don't want to undock separate window, as I need in same page.

Currently when I open chrome dev tools and dock to bottom, it changes my browser viewport height as well.

How do I open dev tools without affecting my page hight?

Also is it possible to drag and move dev tools with in the current page without affecting the current page?

You will be able to see this,
when you have a fixed element with bottom:0;

Comment: There's no way.

Comment: Okay. thanks for the quick response. @wOxxOm